# How can I create a set of collision points for an arbitrary mesh?

Tags: collision-detection, physics, procedural-generation, point-cloud

In my project I am working on automatically deforming an arbitrary mesh with respect to another arbitrary mesh, within the context of user generated content, similar to [this deformer being developed for Second Life](http://www.qarl.com/qLab/?p=76).

In order to preserve the features of a deformed mesh, which may consist of things such as 'folds' for the edge of the mesh, I would like to deform my target with a set of deformers, however defining an appropriate set of deformers has given me trouble and I think now the best way to do it is to create a 'collision mesh'/set of 'control points'. These points will proxy for the target mesh in collision detection and define the deformers used to deform the main mesh. Since I generate it its structure can be more tightly controlled.

I want to create a 'grid' of points which approximate the surface of my mesh, like the control points on a NURBS surface. I was thinking of a technique with principles like those used in the layered depth image technique [here](ftp://ftp.inf.ethz.ch/pub/publications/tech-reports/3xx/395.pdf), but wondered if there was already a good existing solution for what I want to do?

What is the most effective way to create something that approximates a collision mesh for an arbitrary mesh automatically?

Comment: Your second link is an FTP link, and doesn't appear to work too well. Perhaps link to the pdf somewhere using HTTP?

Comment: @Byte56, Hi, I have tried to find another version but that FTP site seems to be the only place. Google has a document viewer, maybe it will be easier to read it via that?: https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:lK7DaJV_ogEJ:ftp://ftp.inf.ethz.ch/pub/publications/tech-reports/3xx/395.pdf+&hl=en&gl=uk&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESiiIJZJICCskmrjmdpboO-AP62y_R1wIFjK9aZn1hh7NaE8m6q23h4nJCGyx9MHMeVqf-IyPG_7XrgIcEP7EdL3E4X4eX40Wa5FILpAkmnr4-ErXY86TpZN4IfjpYMC6RJIJ2hj&sig=AHIEtbQnbo4LNmX4ZhHSeB_S8AyFZFjwng

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tools to generate convex collision geometry](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56884/tools-to-generate-convex-collision-geometry)

Comment: @congusbongus I think that question asks for tools—this one for technique. (Definitely related though.)